# Build a datagrid using HTML5/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to build a datagrid using HTML5/JavaScript.I do not want to use any third party solution due to licensing issues.The requirements of my grid are very simple :

1. Grid showing about 5 columns.
2. First columns contains hyper linked data.
3. Grid needs to have pagination.

Any suggestion on how to implement this ?

Comment: @Steve, I like the eternal question :-) Hopefully the OP is ready to answer it before his question gets closed.

Comment: Most third party solutions you find on the web are free to use without limitations, so I'd be interested to know what kind of licensing issue forces to use *only* homebrewn code.

Answer (score 5):

> I do not want to use any third party solution due to licensing issues.

You should consider the following libraries **distributed under MIT licence**:

- [EditableGrid](http://www.editablegrid.net/) (lots of cool features)
- [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) uses jQuery (MIT licence) (beautiful, easy to extend)

Comment: JQGrid also a good option..

Comment: Update 2019: Handsontable's MIT licensed version is a watered down [community edition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handsontable) and may not be as robust as "rolling your own" anymore. Another good one is [Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) but has also [deprecated the good one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid) in favor of a watered down [community version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-community) and wants [$750-$1,200](https://www.ag-grid.com/license-pricing.php) to use the "robust" version (does grouping). Its a time/skill vs. money decision like anything else. Good luck!